# Do new Macbook Pros come with SATA 3.0Gbps or 6.0Gbps

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware

I'm thinking of buying a SSD or hybrid drive for my new Macbook Pro. Is the SATA connection in new Macbook Pros SATA 3.0Gbps or 6.0Gbps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They come with 6.0 Gbps, which were recently enabled through a firmware update.

[Source](http://www.cultofmac.com/114126/apples-recent-firmware-updates-enabled-sata-6gbps-support-in-new-macbooks/)

Comment: @TKKocheran You should accept the answers when they solved your problem :) That way, when searching this site with the search bar, one can see that this has been solved.

Comment: @Matt Thanks Matt :) And you are welcome TK Kocheran.

Comment: I was just waiting for the 10 minute no-accept window to pass.